# Smarty вызов плагина.

Tags: php

Всем добрый день. :)
Имеется следующий вопрос:
сделал несколько плагинов (функции).
в темплейте я из вызываю следующим методом:
    {function_name}

Работает отлично, без каких - либо проблем, но я не могу понять, как можно вызвать функцию динамически? то есть, чтобы в зависимости от какого - то события, вызывалась соответствующая функция, а не одна и  та же.

Comment: Ож уж этот смарти... Скажите, какие еще могут быть события в шаблоне? Цель шаблонизатора сформировать на основании модели HTML код. Все.

Comment: А никто и не говорит за события в самом шаблоне.  
Предположим, есть  
index.php  
в зависимости от определённых событий, смарти передаёт в шаблон имя нужного плагина.  
а в файле: index.tpl нужно подставить имя этого плагина. Мне в шаблоне логику писать не надо. )

Answer (score 1):

Понял. В таком случае создайте плагин-делегат, который будет вызывать необходимую функцию, в зависимости от переданного параметра. Т.е. что-то вроде такого:

```
function smarty_function_involute_performing($params, $template) {
    if (empty($params['plugin']) || !preg_match('/^[\w\d_]+$/', $params['plugin']) ) {
        trigger_error("assign: missing or incorrect 'plugin' parameter");
        return;
    }

    $function = 'smarty_function_'.$params['plugin'];
    unset($params['plugin']);
    return $function($params, $template);
}
```

Хотя, мне, конечно, не понятно зачем это может понадобится в шаблоне.

Comment: Спасибо, за внимание, но у меня возник следующий вопрос: а как теперь ЭТО вызвать в php, и передать в шаблон?  
Возможно я не с той стороны захожу, но я это делаю для того, чтобы выводить контент на страницу. То есть, у меня есть основной шаблон (index.php index.tpl), и несколько плагинов: news.php/tpl, guestbook.php/tpl, audio.php/tpl, и в овновном шаблоне хочу выызвать плагин в соответствии с запросом через  
     $_GET['page']    
. Как - то так.

Comment: Вероятно мы под плагинами для смарти разные вещи понимаем. Я последний раз работал со смарти достаточно давно и, насколько помню, плагином там считалась любая пользовательская функция или модификатор из директории plugins.
Соответственно приведенная выше функция является таким плагином и должна вызываться в шаблоне примерно так:

    {involute_performing plugin='html_radios' values=$ids output=$names}

Что будет эквивалентно:

    {html_radios values=$ids output=$names}

Answer (score 0):

насколько понял, вам надо вставить разный контент в одно место страницы.
я обычно в таких случаях делаю такой PHP код:

```
$html = $smarty->fetch('шаблон конкретной страницы');
```

потом эту переменную снова передаю в шаблонизатор:

```
$smarty->assign("content",$html);
```

а уже потом вывожу этот HTML блок где надо в шаблоне.

При таком подходе можно сделать иерархичную структуру шаблонов. А плагины смарти можно использовать, например так:

У вас есть параметр $_GET['PAGE']. Вы передаете его в шаблон, а в шаблоне вызываете плагин, который на основании этого параметра, вызывает PHP код, который уже формирует HTML код.

Где это может пригодиться? 
Это может пригодиться при построении компонентной архитектуры проекта. Когда нужно не получать $_GET['page'] от браузера, а например, прописать этот параметр прямо в шаблонах и подключить таким образом некий компонент на странице.